# puma start causes "There is already a server bound to: <socket>" error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, server, puma

I haven't been able to reliably reproduce this issue, so I'll describe what's happening and hope one of you wise puma kids out there can help me out.

I always stop and start puma at the end of my deploy process. I run `pumactl -F <config_path> stop`, which works, and then the command `puma -q -d -e staging -C <config_path>`, which sometimes (not always) causes the following error:

```
[12802] Puma starting in cluster mode... 
[12802] * Version 2.11.3 (ruby 2.1.2-p95), codename: Intrepid Squirrel
[12802] * Min threads: 2, max threads: 4
[12802] * Environment: staging
[12802] * Process workers: 2
[12802] * Phased restart available 
[12802] * Listening on unix:///<app_dir>/tmp/puma/sockets/puma.sock 
<ruby_path>/2.1.0/gems/puma-2.11.3/lib/puma/binder.rb:284:in `add_unix_listener': There is already a server bound to: <app_dir>/tmp/puma/sockets/puma.sock (RuntimeError)
<ruby_path>/2.1.0/gems/puma-2.11.3/lib/puma/binder.rb:124:in `block in parse'
<ruby_path>/2.1.0/gems/puma-2.11.3/lib/puma/binder.rb:82:in `each'
<ruby_path>/2.1.0/gems/puma-2.11.3/lib/puma/binder.rb:82:in `parse'
<ruby_path>/2.1.0/gems/puma-2.11.3/lib/puma/cluster.rb:325:in `run'
<ruby_path>/2.1.0/gems/puma-2.11.3/lib/puma/cli.rb:216:in `run'
<ruby_path>/2.1.0/gems/puma-2.11.3/bin/puma:10:in `<top (required)>'
<ruby_path>/2.1.0/bin/puma:23:in `load'
<ruby_path>/2.1.0/bin/puma:23:in `<main>'
```

If I try to run the same puma start command again afterwards, it works.

Here's my puma config:

```
#!/usr/bin/env puma

directory "<app_dir>/current"
rackup "<app_dir>/current/config.ru"
environment "staging"

pidfile "<app_dir>/tmp/puma/pid"
state_path "<app_dir>/tmp/puma/state"
activate_control_app "<app_dir>/tmp/puma/sockets/pumactl.sock"

stdout_redirect "<app_dir>/shared/log/puma.error.log", "<app_dir>/shared/log/puma.access.log", true

threads 2,4

bind "unix:///<app_dir>/tmp/puma/sockets/puma.sock"

workers 2
```

My questions:

1. How can I reproduce this error?
2. How can I fix it? Is this a problem with puma or with my configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of running both commands...

```
pumactl -F <config_path> stop
puma -q -d -e <env> -C <config_path>
```

just use the restart command:

```
pumactl -F <config_path> restart
```

---

### Explanation

The puma README has a section on [Restarting](https://github.com/puma/puma#restart) that contains no mention of calling the stop and start commands one after the other. Because that use case is unsupported, using the established method to `restart` the puma server will most likely clear up this issue.

### Note

I was unable to consistently reproduce this puma error, so I can't 100% confirm that using `pumactl restart` fixes the problem. (Even though puma's lack of support for `pumactl stop` followed by `puma` implies that it does.) If someone continues to have this issue while using the supported `pumactl restart`, please let me know so I can modify this answer.